# IIS Rewrite Rule - Redirect from one domain binding to another domain binding

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have multiple bindings on my IIS site and I want to catch all requests to

any of the following - domainA.co.uk, www.domainA.co.uk, domainA.com, www.domainA.com

and redirect to a page on one of the other bindings on the site

www.domainB.com/my-folder/

Is this possible with URL Rewrite?

Answer (score 5):

It is possible with url rewrite, you need to use this rule:

```
<rule name="all domains to www.domainB.com/my-folder" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domainA.co.uk$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.domainA.co.uk$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domainA.com$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.domainA.com$" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domainB.com/my-folder/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

It will redirect urls:

- `domainA.co.uk` to `www.domainB.com/my-folder/`
- `www.domainA.co.uk` to `www.domainB.com/my-folder/`
- `domainA.com` to `www.domainB.com/my-folder/`
- `www.domainA.com` to  `www.domainB.com/my-folder/`
- `www.domainA.com/something` to  `www.domainB.com/my-folder/something` (in case if you dont want that, just remove `{R:1}` form rule)

Comment: Want to add that this rule will go into `<rewrite> <rules>` tag under `<system.webServer>` tag obviously.

Answer (score -1):

it is possible you could use the rewrite to redirect the domain

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Force non-WWW and SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">

            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www.(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{C:1}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```